# Apexcharts Bar chart stacked is not working when using JSON

Tags: javascript, json, apexcharts

***When using rendering some data from a JSON in my Apexchart Bars stacked, the result is 3 different bars instead of stacked bars.***

I tried to separate data for "produce" in a JSON Array which supposed to return from ajax call and then pass them inside my Bar Chart and return a new Bar stacked.

**Here is my code:**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/apexcharts/3.26.3/apexcharts.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="chart"></div>
<script>
var options = {
    series: [{
        name: 'Engine block',
        data: [44]
    },
      {
        name: 'Pistons',
        data: [13]
    }, {
        name: 'Cylinder head',
        data: [18]
    }, {
          name: 'Crankshaft',
        data: [21]
        }, {
            name: 'Valves',
            data: [29]
        }
    ],

    chart: {
        type: 'bar',
        height: 110,
        stacked: true,
        toolbar: {
            show: false
        },
        zoom: {
            enabled: false
        }
    },
    dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        textAnchor: 'start',
        style: {
            colors: ['#fff'],
            fontSize: '20px',
            fontFamily: 'Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif',
            fontWeight: 'bold',
        },
        formatter: function (val, opt) {
            return  val
        },
        offsetX: 0,
        dropShadow: {
            enabled: true
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
        bar: {
            horizontal: true,
        },
    },
    xaxis: {
       // categories: ['Engine block', 'SEI LA 2', 'SEI LA 3', 'SEI LA 4'],
        min: 0,
        //max: max,
        labels: {
            show: false
        }

    },
    yaxis: {
        labels: {
            show: false
        }
    },
    fill: {
        opacity: 1
    }
};
    var chartBarPartNo = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#Chart"), options);
    chartBarPartNo.render();

 </Script>
```

The result is :
[image]

**Now, when I read a data, as the code:**
**My data**

```
var data2 = {
    "data2": [
        { "Part": "EB", "Description": "Engine Block", "Quantity": 52 },
        { "Part": "CH", "Description": "Cylinder head", "Quantity": 49 },
        { "Part": "OP", "Description": "Oil pan", "Quantity": 8 }
    ]
}

        a_data = data2;
        var produce = []
        //loop through return data
        $(a_data.data2).each(function (i, v) {
            //push values as x & y
            produce.push({
                "x": v.Part,
                "y": v.Quantity
            })
        })
        chartBarPartNo.updateSeries([{
            name: produce,
            data: produce 
           }])
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass value inside `produce` array as `name,data` pair and then pass this directly in your `updateSeries` method.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
var options = {
  series: [{
      name: 'Engine block',
      data: [44]
    },
    {
      name: 'Pistons',
      data: [13]
    }, {
      name: 'Cylinder head',
      data: [18]
    },
  ],

  chart: {
    type: 'bar',
    height: 110,
    stacked: true,
    toolbar: {
      show: false
    },
    zoom: {
      enabled: false
    }
  },
  dataLabels: {
    enabled: true,
    textAnchor: 'start',
    style: {
      colors: ['#fff'],
      fontSize: '20px',
      fontFamily: 'Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif',
      fontWeight: 'bold',
    },
    formatter: function(val, opt) {
      return val
    },
    offsetX: 0,
    dropShadow: {
      enabled: true
    }
  },
  plotOptions: {
    bar: {
      horizontal: true,
    },
  },
  xaxis: {
    // categories: ['Engine block', 'SEI LA 2', 'SEI LA 3', 'SEI LA 4'],
    min: 0,
    //max: max,
    labels: {
      show: false
    }

  },
  yaxis: {
    labels: {
      show: false
    }
  },
  fill: {
    opacity: 1
  }
};
var chartBarPartNo = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);
chartBarPartNo.render();


var data2 = {
  "data2": [{
      "Part": "EB",
      "Description": "Engine Block",
      "Quantity": 52
    },
    {
      "Part": "CH",
      "Description": "Cylinder head",
      "Quantity": 49
    },
    {
      "Part": "OP",
      "Description": "Oil pan",
      "Quantity": 8
    }
  ]
}

a_data = data2;
var produce = []
//loop through return data
$(a_data.data2).each(function(i, v) {
  produce.push({
    "name": v.Description,
    "data": [v.Quantity]
  })
})
chartBarPartNo.updateSeries(produce) //pass directly..
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/apexcharts/3.26.3/apexcharts.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="chart"></div>
```